# What is the difference between the "complete" and " checkout complete" order statuses?

Tags: 7, commerce, hooks

I am using the Drupal 7 Commerce module. I would like to execute a special code when the payment of the order is completed.

What is the difference between *checkout complete* and *complete*?

I googled and I found suggestions for these hook implementations.

#### First option

```php
function mymodule_commerce_order_update($order) {
  if ($order->status == 'completed' ) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

#### Second option

```php
function my_module_commerce_order_presave($order) {
  if ($order->status == 'completed' ) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

###Third option

I found some suggestions to implement `hook_commerce_order_updated()`.

#### Fourth option

```php
function mymodule_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
  if ($order->status == 'completed' ) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above. You should be using `hook_commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full()`, which is always invoked the first time an order's balance drops to $0 or less.

Read more about it in [commerce/modules/payment/commerce_payment.api.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/7.x-1.x/modules/payment/commerce_payment.api.php#L382).